# Xcode stuck while building and not allowing any others apps to open

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, macos-catalina

I am on catalina 10.15.5 
running xcode 11.3 
in scripts it is running google crashlytics/run execution file
Whenever i am building xcode it is getting stuck at some point and doesn't allow the user to quit. need to force quit the xcode.
After that it doesn't allow users to open other apps. app keeps on hopping and then allows the user to force quite the app.
Need to shutdown mac and start again.

run execution file contains below code -

```
#!/bin/sh

# Copyright 2019 Google
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#
# run
#
# This script is meant to be run as a Run Script in the "Build Phases" section
# of your Xcode project. It sends debug symbols to symbolicate stacktraces,
# sends build events to track versions, and onboards apps for Crashlytics.
#
# This script calls upload-symbols twice:
#
# 1) First it calls upload-symbols synchronously in "validation" mode. If the
#    script finds issues with the build environment, it will report errors to Xcode.
#    In validation mode it exits before doing any time consuming work.
#
# 2) Then it calls upload-symbols in the background to actually send the build
#    event and upload symbols. It does this in the background so that it doesn't
#    slow down your builds. If an error happens here, you won't see it in Xcode.
#
# You can find the output for the background execution in Console.app, by
# searching for "upload-symbols".
#
# If you want verbose output, you can pass the --debug flag to this script
#

#  Figure out where we're being called from
DIR=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )

#  If the first argument is specified without a dash, treat it as the Fabric API
#  Key and add it as an argument.
if [ -z "$1" ] || [[ $1 == -* ]]; then
  API_KEY_ARG=""
else
  API_KEY_ARG="-a $1"; shift
fi

#  Build up the arguments list, passing through any flags added after the
#  API Key
ARGUMENTS="$API_KEY_ARG $@"
VALIDATE_ARGUMENTS="$ARGUMENTS --build-phase --validate"
UPLOAD_ARGUMENTS="$ARGUMENTS --build-phase"

# Quote the path to handle folders with special characters
COMMAND_PATH="\"$DIR/upload-symbols\" "

#  Ensure params are as expected, run in sync mode to validate,
#  and cause a build error if validation fails
eval $COMMAND_PATH$VALIDATE_ARGUMENTS
return_code=$?

if [[ $return_code != 0 ]]; then
  exit $return_code
fi

#  Verification passed, convert and upload cSYMs in the background to prevent
#  build delays
#
#  Note: Validation is performed again at this step before upload
#
#  Note: Output can still be found in Console.app, by searching for
#        "upload-symbols"
#
eval $COMMAND_PATH$UPLOAD_ARGUMENTS > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

File path was causing this issue. Solved after changing root.